# how to install/polymer without docs

Tags: polymer, bower, bower-install

Currently i am installing polymer with

`bower install Polymer\core-elements`

which includes so many unnecessary files such as docs and eg. which in returns increases my app size.

Is there a way to get only the required/necessary files.

Comment: Vulcanize. Minify. Use gulp or grunt to do this automatically.

Comment: polymer doesn't provide any cli tool to fetch only required files.?

Comment: Polymer is a library like jquery, not a framework. Either way, if you don't like gulp or grunt, you can do a makefile instead.